# scroll width is not change with css

Tags: css

i try to make div with images gallery scrolling horizontal.
i give the scroll width css but it is not applied. the background-color is applied well.

see my css code below:

```
            #scroll {
                margin:100px auto;
                overflow:auto;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                }
            #scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
                    width: 6px !important;
                    background:#C9C5C5;
                }
```

when using vertical scroll the width is applied well:
                    {
                    overflow-x: hidden;
                    overflow-y: auto;
                    }

i hope you can help me with it.
thanks a lot!

the scroll width is not changed to 6px

Comment: Did you apply width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is **horizontal** so you need is not '*width*' but '*height*'
 `#scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 6px !important;
    background:#C9C5C5;
}`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/que5kvzr/)